# How NOT to change file extension when uploading it?

Tags: laravel, validation, upload, mp3

In my Laravel project I need to upload mp3 files, However Laravel using `mpga` as a mime type to validate `mp3` files type I found that in this [answer](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/validation-upload-only-mp3-wav-or-ogg?page=1#reply=101559).

```php
$results = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            "song" => "required|file|mimes:mpga|max:8192",
        ]);
```

I am okay with that but my problem is the file is stored with `mpga` extension, I know the reason behind this weird action from this [answer](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-saves-mp3-files-as-mpga?page=1#reply=529736).

**How I store the file**

```php
// Upload the song
$filePath = $request->song->store("public/songs");
```

But I want to store the file with `mp3` extension.

Comment: Add the code of how are you storing the file

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your code, the best I can suggest is to use the [putFileAs()](https://laravel.com/api/6.x/Illuminate/Filesystem/FilesystemAdapter.html#method_putFileAs) method from the `Storage` class.

This method allows you to specify a file name when storing your file:

```php
use Illuminate\Http\File;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

// Manually specify a file name:
Storage::putFileAs(
    'folder',
    new File('/path/to/uploaded-music.mp3'), 
    'stored-song-name.mp3'
);
```

See Laravel doc: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/filesystem#storing-files

---

Edit: If you want to keep Laravel random file naming just like the `putFile()` method does, you can generate a random string and append your extension:

```php
use Illuminate\Http\File;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

// Manually specify a file name:
Storage::putFileAs(
    'folder',
    new File('/path/to/uploaded-music.mp3'), 
    Str::random(40) . '.mp3'
);
```

If you look at [Laravel source code](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/641a7cda8280ecd3035616d4ce6434434b116624/src/Illuminate/Http/FileHelpers.php#L48), this is how `putFile()` does it to generate a random file name.

Comment: I am looking for a way to it while keeping Laravel handles file naming process.

Answer (score 0):

[Lobsterbaz's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4257068/lobsterbaz) answer works perfectly, and i also want to give alternative to that answer which will help you to keep your file's extension as it is.

Laravel changes `mp3` file's extension as `mpga` after uploading, so here i will show you how to keep mp3 file's extension as it is after uploading, below code will help you to do it:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Str;


$path = $request->file('song')->storeAs(
    'songs', Str::random(40).".mp3"
);
```

Congrats, Now your song will be stored as mp3, but be sure to upload mp3 files only and put validation of mimes for mp3 otherwise it can break the file.